# Data Annotation will not raise client side validation on Partial views

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an asp.net MVC web application, and I have the following main view:-

```
@model TMS.ViewModels.ServerOnIT360Only
<div id ="VMTable2">

                        <div class="pagedList" data-tms-target="#VMTable">
                         @Html.PagedListPager(Model.Resources , page => Url.Action("IT360Asset","Server", new { page }),
                         PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(PagedListRenderOptions.ClassicPlusFirstAndLast, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "VMTable2" , LoadingElementId="progress2" }))

                        </div>
                             <img src="~/Content/Ajax-loader-bar.gif" class="loadingimage" id="progress2" />

                        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Server/_ServerTable2.cshtml",Model)
                    <img src="~/Content/Ajax-loader-bar.gif" class="loadingimage" id="progress3" />
                             <div class="pagedList" data-tms-target="#VMTable">
                         @Html.PagedListPager(Model.Resources , page => Url.Action("IT360Asset","Server", new { page }),
                         PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(PagedListRenderOptions.ClassicPlusFirstAndLast, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "VMTable2" , LoadingElementId="progress3"}))

                        </div>  </div>
```

And the following _ServerTable2.cshtml partial view, which will be rendered when the user clicks on the paging numbers:-

```
@model TMS.ViewModels.ServerOnIT360Only
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
    <tr>
        //code goes here....
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.Resources) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RESOURCENAME)
        </td>
         <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SystemInfo.MODEL)
        </td>


        //code goes here
         <td id = "@item.RESOURCEID">



@using (Ajax.BeginForm("IT360Asset","Server", new AjaxOptions {
 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
 UpdateTargetId =   item.RESOURCEID.ToString() ,
 LoadingElementId = item.RESOURCEID.ToString() + "imag",
 HttpMethod = "POST"


}


)){


    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   <span class="f"> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.Server.RoleID)</span>

     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Server.RoleID, ((IEnumerable<TMS.Models.TechnologyRole>)ViewBag.TechRole).Select(option => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.Name),
    Value = option.RoleID.ToString(),
    Selected = (Model.Server != null) && (option.RoleID == Model.Server.RoleID)
}), "Choose...", new  {@class="SmallDropDown" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Server.RoleID)



   <span class="f">Rack</span>

     @Html.DropDownListFor(model =>model.Server.RackID, ((IEnumerable<TMS.Models.TMSRack>)ViewBag.Racks).Select(option => new SelectListItem {
        Text = (option == null ? "None" : option.Technology.Tag), 
        Value = option.TMSRackID.ToString(),
        Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.Server != null) && (option.TMSRackID == Model.Server.RackID)
    }), "Choose...",new  {@class="SmallDropDown" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Server.RackID)


    @Html.Hidden("ResourceID", item.RESOURCEID)
    @Html.Hidden("Product",item.ComponentDefinition.COMPONENTNAME)
    @Html.Hidden("Model", item.SystemInfo.MODEL)


 <input type="submit" value="Add To TMS" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    <img src="~/Content/Ajax-loader-bar.gif" class="loadingimage" id="@(item.RESOURCEID.ToString())imag"/>
}
</tr>
}

</table>

  @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Now when a user navigate to the main view, and he clicks on the Ajax.BeginForm , all the client side validation will work well (basically the [Required] validation ). But if the user navigate to the Page number 2 and call the action method that render the partial view only; Then all the client side validation will stop working ?
can anyone advice how I can force these clients side validation to work when partial view is rendered. currently the client side validation will only work if the action method render the main view directly, but after clicking on the paging which will only render _ServerTable2.cshtml partial view, then the client side validation will not work, and users can submit the form even if all the required fields are empty.
Can anyone advice what is causing this problem , and how i can solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have jquery.validate.unobtrusive in your js bundle. Otherwise you will need to add it.

You need to run

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("Selector to form need validation");
```

After the ajax content been loaded in order to enable the client side validation on ajax-loaded contents.

Easiest way for your case is to add:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#VMTable2 form");
    });
</script>
```

To your partial. However this MAY cause some trouble since your initial non-ajax page content is using the same partial.

If the above prompt you any script error, then you need to add the

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#VMTable2 form");
```

Into the "OnComplete" of your Paginator's AjaxOptions instead.